# Can Google Home access MP3 files on PC or Raspberry?

Tags: mp3, music

How do I get Google Home Mini to access Raspberry Pi or PC MP3 files on command?

The YouTube subscription isn't what I'm looking for. I want to play music and movies from my own library.

Can I get Google Home to control Kodi or just simply play MP3s on the Mini from my own library?

Comment: https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=314096